# Why GridSearchCV has higher score with a subset of parameters?

Tags: decision-tree, gridsearchcv

Below is my code, I run it twice. The first one with "criterion": ['gini', 'entropy'] and the second one with just 'entropy' ('gini' was removed), nothing else changed. I expected with less number of combinations, the score must be equal or lower, but it was higher - How is it possible?? No randomness and those numbers repeated all the times.

- Using *"criterion": [**'gini'**, 'entropy']* got score of 0.850
- Using *"criterion": ['entropy']* got score of 0.871 (higher)

```
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataX, dataY, test_size=0.2, random_state=10, stratify=dataY)
    gs_params = {
        "criterion": ['gini', 'entropy'],
        "max_depth": [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15],
        "min_samples_split": range(2, 9, 2),
        "min_samples_leaf": range(1, 5)
    }
    
    gs = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=gs_params, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1,
                      cv=5, scoring='f1_weighted', refit=True)
    
    clf = Pipeline([
        ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
        ('features1', SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=80), threshold='median')),
        ('features2', SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=81), threshold='median')),
        ('features3', SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=82), threshold='median')),
        ('gs', gs)
    ])
    
    clf.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values)
    test_score_opt = clf.score(X_test.values, y_test.values)
```

Comment: Could it be due to gini overfitting more on the train data? When running `fit()` you find the best model parameters for the training data, but then you test it on different test data. When you remove the gini parameter, then you get a model that is slightly worse after fitting, but performs better on the test data.

Comment: A set of parameters working well on training data is no guarantee of working well on test data. It means different sets of parameters will get different scores on unseen test data.

Comment: That's kind of my point. I suspect that grid search is finding an optimal parameter combination - which includes using gini as the loss - on the training data. However, once you test that model configuration on the test data, it performs worse than if you had used the best parameter combination that included the entropy loss.